# Renaming registers in MIPS assembly level programing

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing a MIPS code and I think it will be convenient for me to rename some registers to increase readability of the code.

For example if I call $t0 as $count, etc.

Is there any way we can alias/rename these registers in MIPS?

(I am looking for a #define equivalent in MIPS)

Comment: This may be a feature of your assembler. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Qtspim mips simulator. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: The assembler is key here, not the simulator. The simulator runs compiled machine code, doesn't it?

Comment: How do you figure out what the assembler is? I assumed my simulator came with something inbuilt to convert the code to binary.

Comment: It's time to read the documentation on qtspim and see what it can do.

Comment: Will do, sorry.

Comment: I have played with this once (not on MIPS) and found that it perhaps isn't such a great idea. If you name some registers, you will still have to remember which they are so you don't accidentally reuse them for some other calculations.

Comment: `QtSpim` doesn't have a true "equate" capability. The `mars` simulator http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/ does. I prefer it over spim. In `mars`, you _could_ do: `.eqv count $t0`/`li count,32`, but I'd recommend _against_ it for the same reasons as Bo. Many years ago, in asm, I tried the same thing as you're proposing. In the end, it made the code _harder_ to read and maintain. Get the effect with the sidebar comments. Do (e.g.) `li $t0,32 # set count`